# K&R Chapter 5.4: Questions on passage regarding stacks

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am on Chapter 5.4 of the "C Programming Language (2nd Edition)" and I came across a passage regarding memory allocation that I cannot get a mental grasp of:

In reference to the book's rudimentary implementation of memory allocation with the functions alloc(n) and afree(p)

> C is consistent and regular in its approach to address arithmetic; its integration of pointers, arrays, and address arithmetic is one of the strengths of the language. Let us illustrate by writing a rudimentary storage allocator. There are two routines. The first, alloc(n), returns a pointer to n consecutive character positions, which can be used by the caller of alloc for storing characters. The second, afree(p), releases the storage thus acquired so it can be re-used later. The routines are ``rudimentary'' because the calls to afree must be made in the opposite order to the calls made on alloc. That is, the storage managed by alloc and afree is a stack, or last-in, first-out. The standard library provides analogous functions called malloc and free that have no such restrictions;

The problem I have understanding is when the passage states the routines are 'rudimentary' because calls to afree must be made in the opposite order to the calls made on alloc. Does that mean the function afree must be called first before making use of the function alloc? I understand how the stack data structure behaves but I am unsure of its context in stating the function calls "must be made in the opposite order".

Also, the the last sentence of the paragraph states malloc and free having no such restrictions. What are the restrictions they are referring to?

Comment: The restrictions being referred to is that the calls to afree must be made in the opposite order to the calls to alloc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think an example will best explain this.

If I make the calls:

```
a = alloc(10);
b = alloc(10);
c = alloc(10);
```

I must call afree in this order:

```
afree(c);
afree(b);
afree(a);
```

That is the rudimentary implementation.  In the C language you do not need to call free in reverse order of how you called malloc.  You can malloc multiple times and then free later.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Due to the book's implementation of the memory allocation, if we were to not call afree in the opposite order, then there a good chance of overwriting other allocated data. Thank you, I have been thinking about this all day.

Answer (score 2):

It means if you call:

```
p1 = alloc(n1);
p2 = alloc(n2);
```

you must call:

```
afree(p2);
afree(p1);
```

This restriction (the mandated order of the calls) is not present in malloc and free (i.e. using malloc and free you can allocate/release in any order).

Why this is so is because `alloc` saves the sizes of the allocations in a stack, but not the locations so basically what these functions do is:

alloc - allocate n bytes. Push n into stack and return pointer to allocated memory.
afree - Pop number from stack and free said number of bytes of memory starting at the position in the pointer passed as a function parameter.

If you don't call them in order chaos ensues.

Comment: Although it would be a further restriction, one could free allocated bytes out of order and re-allocate with the same size with no problems right?

Comment: Yes, but you are then making implementation assumptions. The formal specification says alloc and afree must be called in reverse order. The reason is that the original implementation used a stack. You cannot assume every implementation in every platform will use a stack, so you should stick to the "contract".

Answer (score 0):

They're stating that their *custom* `alloc` and `afree` routines are "rudimentary" because in their implementation all `afree` calls must be made in the reverse order of all the `alloc` calls.

This is a **restriction** due to their routines being "rudimentary" (and probably implemented with a simple stack instead of some more complex record-keeping method).

The actual library routines `malloc` and `free` on the other hand are **not** "rudimentary" and **not** restricted - `free` calls do **not** have to be called in the reverse order of all `malloc` calls.

Answer (score 0):

The restrictions being referred to is that the calls to afree must be made in the opposite order to the calls to alloc.

malloc and free use a huge area called the 'heap'.

The malloc on the initial call, creates two linked lists,

the first is all the unallocated space in the heap.

the second is all the allocated space on the heap.

At first, the first entry on the unallocated linked list is all in a single entry that contains all of the heap.

The allocated list is empty.

With out going into detail, each allocation (via malloc)

1) adds an entry to the allocated list indicating the size the caller requested
and where it is located in the heap

2) changes the unallocated list to only show the parts of the heap that are not currently allocated.

3) returns a pointer to the (new) allocated list

free doesn't really care about the order of its' being called

free takes the pointer passed to it, finds that entry in the allocated linked list

removed that entry from the allocated linked list

places that entry into the unallocated linked list

trys to merge adjacent entrys from the unallocated linked list into 
a single entry in the unallocated linked list.
(a form of garbage collection)